# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running JUnit test in Netbeans

Tags: java, android, junit

I am building an Android hello world application in Netbeans. It's building properly and I am able to run in the emulator also.

But when creating and running the Junit test I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Edit your question to include the entire error message and stacktrace.

Answer (score 16):

Check the manifest of your test project, for example `HelloWorldTest/AndroidManifest.xml`. The `android:targetPackage` attribute of the `instrumentation` markup should target the package in your application, for example, `com.example.helloworld`. *Not* the test package of your test project (eg. `com.example.helloworld.test`).

Comment: *facepalm* you just saved me 1 hour of searching. It's a common mistake and yet I tend to overlook it from time to time :)

Comment: Eh eh _I_ lost an hour myself with that mistake. :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply `AndroidManifest.xml -> manifest -> package` of main application should match `AndroidManifest.xml -> manifest -> instrumentation -> android:targetPackage` of the test application.

Comment: But if he runs simply no instrumentation test but plain old jUnit?

Answer (score 0):

The full error message contains the name of the class, that wasn't found *on the classpath*. Double check if the classpath that is used for running the test includes all required classes and libraries (your class files, junit.jar, android specific libaries).

Answer (score 0):

I find that a rebuild usually finds the classes (as it is a classpath issue). Netbeans seems to aggressively compile existing tests, but the main source code (from a maven setting at least) is not always available.

I've started running full builds to try address this. There might be a plugin that addresses this but I haven't found it yet.

EDIT: [This](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave) might help.

Comment: I think he has more a android-netbeans-integration problem. you mentioned a problem which occurs if compile on save is enabled for the project sources too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about netbeans specifics, but the problem is probably the same.

[FragmentActivity can not be tested via ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561353/fragmentactivity-can-not-be-tested-via-activityinstrumentationtestcase2)

Your test project can be using a different android compatibility library than your main project, and that causes this weird errors.