# FragmentActivity Junit Testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, fragment

Me used `Fragment` of Android Compatibility Package, using the `android-support-v4.jar`. But I can't do the JUnit test on this.

My main `FragmentActivity` class is declared as follows

```
public class MyActivityClass extends FragmentActivity{
...............
}
```

Then in my test project

```
public class MyActivityClassTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivityClass> {
    public MyActivityClassTest() {  
        super("com.android.myproject", MyActivityClass.class);
    }
    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        ...................
    }

    public void testPreconditions() {
        .................
    }
    public void testNotNull(){
        ................
    }
}
```

But when I run as `Android JUnit Test` produce `FailedToCreateTests[Runner:Junit3]`
**Failure Trace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:239)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:430)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.android.myproject.test.MyActivityClassTest.<init>(MyActivityClassTest.java:28)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:87)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:263)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:185)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:336)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3982)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:119)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1901)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.myproject.MyActivityClass
... 19 more
```

When I changed `MyActivityClass` to extends `Activity` it worked fine `(MyActivityClass extends Activity`)
Me used the same `android-support-v4.jar` in my both test and main project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution

The problem was

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.myproject.MyActivityClass
```

It cannot find the class path even though I refer the same jar in both projects ( I also tried by using separate jar for both the project )

Now, I created my testing environment in the **same project**, then it worked

In my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest...>
    <!-- For doing JUnit test, Instrumentation Start (remove later) -->
    <instrumentation
        android:targetPackage="com.pe.android.isccasinos"
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
    <!-- For doing JUnit test, Instrumentation End (remove later) -->   
    <application ...>
    ................
    <!-- For doing JUnit test, add library starting (remove later) -->
        <uses-library
            android:name="android.test.runner" />
        <!-- For doing JUnit test, add library ending (remove later) -->
    </application>
<manifest>
```

Then I added my Testing class in my special package for testing

```
extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<fragmentActivity>
```

Now everything is working fine :)

Comment: This successfully works around it but Id still like to know why it happens when using a separate test project...

Answer (score 7):

`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` is compatible with `Fragments`. You should only follow the steps mentioned in [Android Testing: External libraries](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-testing-external-libraries.html), which has been updated to cover the case of the `android-support-v4.jar` too.

Then, you will be able to write tests like this one:

```
public void testFragmentManager() {
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    assertNotNull(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
}
```

or whatever you need to test.

Comment: Thanks Dtmilano, That link you provided is really helpful, but I have added that build path for External libraries. Still bad luck for me. When I created my testing in the same project it worked :)

Comment: What you published is a workaround, that will lead you to another problem: how not to ship the tests with your app.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse ? I'm sure it works because I'm using it.

Comment: Yes me using eclipse :( And if I use same project as test, will that make problem for me later?:( I think after completing my project I will delete that extra testing package and manifest entries for testing. will that be fine?

Comment: follow http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-testing-external-libraries.html I still met compile when run ant ant build ant debug in the test project. Such as: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
    [javac] import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

Comment: Then I add a link from the android.support.v4 in main project to my test project, the build is passed but when running test with "ant debug test ", still met Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mobile.client.activity.QuestionListActivity

Comment: But there is a problem with support fragments. `fragment.getView()` returns null. But with android.app.Fragments it works fine. I'm using (extending) ActivityUnitTestCase. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

See this question for a better answer:

[FragmentActivity can not be tested via ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561353/fragmentactivity-can-not-be-tested-via-activityinstrumentationtestcase2)

You need to export the reference to the compatibility library from your app.

Answer (score 1):

This is late, but I solve the same issue by **only** adding the **android-support-v4.jar** dependency to the main project, and removing it from the test project.

Then, make sure the main project is on the **build path** of the test project.
Do the same for any other libraries the main, and test projects might share.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` is not compatible with `Fragments`.
You should try something like [Robolectric](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric).

Comment: No it is compatible. When I created my testing in the same project it worked. Thanks Marcarse for that link. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried almost a day to deal with this issue and found a solution from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561353/fragmentactivity-can-not-be-tested-via-activityinstrumentationtestcase2/5645277#5645277)

Basically your android-support-v4.jar (in my case) is used in the Application should be same with what you have used in your Test application. The best way to do is, remove the same jar from the libs directory of your test project and export the same from your Application project. That way you can get rid of this issue for sure.