# NoClassDefFoundError of a source file in Android Test on IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror, ormlite

**EDIT**

After more investigation, it discovered that this has *ant test* command also doesn't work, so it's not a IntelliJ issue.

There is some warnings at app launch which suggest that the problem comes from a wrong link with ormlite framework :

```
WARN/dalvikvm(22209): Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Lcom/example/android/app/noclassdef/module/dao/BaseBrowserDAO;(0x4051f5e8):0x98558 ref [Lcom/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao;] Lcom/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao;(0x4051f5e8):0x97ec0

WARN/dalvikvm(22209): (Lcom/example/android/app/noclassdef/module/dao/BaseBrowserDAO; had used a different Lcom/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao; during pre-verification)

WARN/dalvikvm(22209): Link of class 'Lcom/example/android/app/noclassdef/module/dao/BaseBrowserDAO;' failed
```

But this only happen in the test project, the main project has no issues.

I found that since R17 the jar 'really' needs to be in libs directory, so ithought maybe i should copy the jars in the test project libs directory, but it didn't change anything.

**Original**

My Android test project doesn't run on Android, i get the following error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mycompany.android.module.shop.database.MyDBHelper
at com.mycompany.android.module.shop.dao.DAOFactory.(DAOFactory.java:51)
at com.mycompany.android.module.shop.dao.DAOFactory.initSingleton(DAOFactory.java:58)
at com.mycompany.android.app.shop.test.EShopBaseTestCase.setUp(EShopBaseTestCase.java:41)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.android.module.shop.database.MyDBHelper in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/data/app/com.mycompany.android.app.shop.test-1.apk:/mnt/asec/com.mycompany.android.app.shop-1/pkg.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
... 12 more
```

**The test run without any problem on Eclipse so i guess it's a configuration issue.**

**The 'missing' class is a source class of the App, it's not in a jar nor in any external framework.**

What puzzle me more is, looking at the stacktrace com.mycompany.android.module.shop.dao.DAOFactory is present but not com.mycompany.android.module.shop.database.MyDBHelper (which are in the same project...)

Anyone with an idea ? I've been stuck on it for some time now. It's not the first time I'm using test project with IntelliJ so I compared my configuration with working project but i found no differences at all...

Comment: Try [IDEA 12.0.3](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP), rebuild the project, if it doesn't help, share a sample project to reproduce it.

Comment: I'm using 12.0.1. I'm not sure if i can reproduce the problem as all my other test projects works fine...

Comment: Try the new version, also try disabling [this option](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3550/20121206235318.png).

Comment: I tried the new version and disabling the option but nothing changed. I've edited my question with a link to a zip file of a sample project which reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, actually the important message was

> [...] had used a different Lcom/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao; during pre-verification

Which means that my ormlite jars where copied in each project instead of being exported properly in the main project.

Just checking the "export" checkbox on the jar solve the situation.

I was greatly help by [FragmentActivity can not be tested via ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561353/fragmentactivity-can-not-be-tested-via-activityinstrumentationtestcase2)