# NoClassDefFoundError FragmentActivity test

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a simple Android Activity test that checks that a new Activity is started when a button is clicked. The code:

```
public class LoginActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {

public LoginActivityTest() {
    super(LoginActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

    mActivity = getActivity();

    mLoginButton = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    mSkipButton = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.skip_button);
}

{...}

public void testSkipButton() {
    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor =
    getInstrumentation().addMonitor(
        "com.mycompany.myproject.view.QuestionsActivity",  null, false);

    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSkipButton.requestFocus();
            mSkipButton.performClick();
        }
    });

    QuestionsActivity nextActivity =
            (QuestionsActivity) getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, 20);
    assertNotNull(nextActivity);
    nextActivity.finish();
}

private LoginActivity mActivity;
private Button mLoginButton;
private Button mSkipButton;
}
```

When I reach waitForMonitorWithTimeout() a NoClassDefFoundException is raised.

It's important to take into account that QuestionsActivity (the activity that should be launched) is a **FragmentActivity**, not an Activity, but FragmentActivity inherits from Activity, so I really don't understand what's happening there. Maybe InstrumentationTest cannot deal with Fragments or FragmentActivities.

mActivity is the current Activity that it's being tested, and it's a pure Activity.

Please, help!

Comment: do you have the supportLib included in your Test Project?

Comment: Yep, I have the android-support-v4 library included.

Comment: I tried with an Activity as target instead of a FragmentActivity and now I get a null in "nextActivity" so the assertNotNull fails. I wonder if this work at all...
Randomly I get NullPointerExceptions when I run 2 tests that perform a simple click with no checks...

Comment: The null got using a regular Activity was due to the timeout: it's in milliseconds, not in seconds, as the documentation wrongly states (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#waitForMonitorWithTimeout%28android.app.Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor,%20long%29).

Comment: More info: the problem is here (Instrumentation class):
        public final Activity waitForActivity() {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (mLastActivity == null) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Activity res = mLastActivity;
                mLastActivity = null;
                return res;
            }
        }
When running wait() I get a java.lang.IllegalAccessError; I think that a wait() is not allowed in the UI thread IIRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I added a reference to the support library from the testing project. See this link:
[FragmentActivity can not be tested via ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561353/fragmentactivity-can-not-be-tested-via-activityinstrumentationtestcase2)

Now tests work fine :)