# Issues running Espresso instrument tests on Dalvik runtime devices

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I'm running across a similar issue to [FragmentActivity can not be tested via ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561353/fragmentactivity-can-not-be-tested-via-activityinstrumentationtestcase2)

The problem with the top solution there is that only applies to using the Eclipse build system. I'm using Gradle for my project.

On my Nexus 5 running the ART runtime, my Espresso instrument tests run perfectly. When I use a Nexus 4 on the Dalvik runtime or an emulator, I run into an exception that doesn't occur when running the app outside of the testing framework.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.packagename.fragment.ProgressDialogFragment
```

In the logs, I find these suspicious messages similar to the linked question:

```
Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Landroid/support/v4/app/DialogFragment2;(0x41e969d8):0x76064000 ref [Landroid/support/v4/app/DialogFragment;] Landroid/support/v4/app/DialogFragment;(0x41e969d8):0x75883000
(Landroid/support/v4/app/DialogFragment2; had used a different Landroid/support/v4/app/DialogFragment; during pre-verification)
Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/DialogFragment2; (271)
Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/DialogFragment2;' failed
Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/packagename/fragment/ProgressDialogFragment; (270)
Link of class 'Lcom/packagename/fragment/ProgressDialogFragment;' failed
Could not find method com.packagename.fragment.ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance, referenced from method com.packagename.activity.IntroActivity.doJoin
VFY: unable to resolve static method 47365: Lcom/packagename/fragment/ProgressDialogFragment;.newInstance (I)Landroid/support/v4/app/DialogFragment2;
VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0063
```

`ProgressDialogFragment` is a subclass of `DialogFragment2` which is a subclass of the Android support library's `DialogFragment` class

Here are the dependencies in my Gradle file if that helps:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.+'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.+'

    compile 'fr.avianey:facebook-android-api:+@aar'

    compile 'com.squareup.mimecraft:mimecraft:1.1.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.5.+'

    compile 'eu.inmite.android.lib:android-styled-dialogs:1.1.+@aar'

    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:3.+'

    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:0.7.+'

    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:0.9.+'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:0.9.+'

    apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${project.ext.butterKnifeVersion}"
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${project.ext.butterKnifeVersion}"

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    // Excluded modules were determined from here: https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle
    instrumentTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs-test', include: '*.jar')
    instrumentTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1',
            'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'

    instrumentTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    instrumentTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-plugin-registry'
        exclude module: 'maven-profile'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'nekohtml'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-shared'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
    instrumentTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.+'
```

So my question is how can I make sure that the same support library is being used between the application APK and the test APK? I've already tried adding in `instrumentTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'` to ensure the same support library version but that didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much pain, sweat and tears. I managed to determine the solution. Simply adding `exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'` to the list of excludes for Robolectric allowed Robolectric to continue to work while having it not crash on the Dalvik runtime.

Comment: Just to let other know - this also solved my issue when a simple test wouldn't start  after adding `appcompat` library. `java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:238)`

Comment: androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3+') {
   exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'){
   exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
2 days of tears...
Thank you guys!!!