# Unable to run android espresso tests

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to run Android espresso test but they keep failing with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.blokura.testexample.app.MainActivity

I'm using Jake Wharton's double espresso plugin.

I tried Jake's setup as seen at [github repo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso) and [deckard](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) without luck.

I don't know what i'm missing.

This is the project structure
[image: project structure]

And this is the build.gradle file source code:

```
    apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r3'
}
```

EspressoTest.java

```
package com.blokura.testexample.app;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;

import com.blokura.testexample.app.MainActivity;

import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.lang.Override;

@LargeTest
public class EspressoTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity>{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public EspressoTest() {
        super("com.blokura.testexample.app", MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        getActivity();
    }

    public void testCheckText() {
        onView(withId(R.id.text))
                .check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.blokura.testexample.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Complete log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:238)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:167)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:87)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:262)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:184)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:379)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:114)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4335)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.blokura.testexample.app.MainActivity
at com.blokura.testexample.app.EspressoTest.<init>(EspressoTest.java:20)
... 19 more
```

Comment: See the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996376/issues-running-espresso-instrument-tests-on-dalvik-runtime-devices.  Sounds like it could be the same issue.

Comment: @jdonmoyer it was the same issue, as I wrote down in my answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: please if you have any project in android studio with working Idle resource, share with as (me) on github. I am trying to implement espresso with idling resource for week:((
I have posted my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016562/android-espresso-wrong-set-up-or-work-not-stable
But if anyone has any android studio working project with Idle espresso test, please, share!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uff,
I forgot to exclude support library in the gradle file :(

Here's the correct build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3'
    androidTestCompile ('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r3') {
        exclude group:'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, change `test` folder by `androidTest`. Second, check the last version of [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso). For example, I used this gradle setting for a project and it worked for me:

```
***
android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"        
  defaultConfig {
     testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     ***
  }
  ***
}    
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Please see here for an up-to-date configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50179598/905686

Answer (score 0):

Gradle's latest convention in Android Studio is to call your tests directory '**androidTest**'.  Then in your build.gradle file you need to put:

```
    androidTest.setRoot('androidTest')
    androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['androidTest/java']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the issue is not with the name of the test folder, but with the way handles test dependencies. There's a bug report filled here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65445 about this issue.