# What are the correct dependencies for Espresso tests?

Tags: dependencies, android-espresso

On different official Android sites there is different information on how to set up Espresso tests:

1) https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing

```java
dependencies {
    // Other dependencies ...
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

2) https://developer.android.com/studio/test/

```java
dependencies {
    // Required for local unit tests (JUnit 4 framework)
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Required for instrumented tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
}
```

3) https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup

```java
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
```

- With some configurations I get library conflicts ((2) explains that this is due to dependencies requiring the same other dependency but with different versions).

  - Even excluding with

  `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  }`
  might not help.
- With some configurations I get an error on the import of `android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule`

Answer (score 0):

No. 3 seems to work, with and without the exclude-part:

```java
dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}
```

It seems that for older espresso versions, like `2.2.2`, one did not need a separate dependency for `android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule` import.

Answer (score 0):

Espresso is an instrumentation test. These are placed in a different folder than Unit Tests. They are kept in the androidTest/java package. So keep that in mind when using dependencies. For instrumentation tests you need to use

```
androidTestImplementation
```

vs

```
testImplementation
```

So assuming that your Espresso test class is in app->src->androidTest->java location, this should work:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

For somebody who might look for this, this is my `build.gradle` setup with Cucumber + Espresso + Barista:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lomza.uitestsapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testApplicationId "com.lomza.uitestsapp.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.lomza.uitestsapp.tests.GroceriesAppAndroidTestRunner"
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            assets {
                assets.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/assets']
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-android:4.4.1"
    androidTestImplementation('com.schibsted.spain:barista:3.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
    }
}
```

Check my whole [tutorial](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/android-app-ui-tests-with-cucumber-espresso-barista-1604021fed6c) to see it in action.